# How to place fragment view holder below toolbar with androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I am trying to create a simple layout with my fragment holder below the toolar, but despite applying all the solutions toolbar overlaps the fragment holder layout. Here is my code.

```
    [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DashboardActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/dashboardFragmentContainerView"
        android:background="@color/black"

        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"



       />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:id="@+id/toolbarContainer"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme"
                app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            app:menu="@menu/main_menu"

            />



</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have added screenshot for reference , any solutions ?
Thanks :)

Comment: Move the `<FragmentContainerView>` into the `<LinearLayout>`, after the `<Toolbar>`, and then set `android:orientation="vertical"` on the `<LinearLayout>`. Probably also want `android:layout_height="match_parent"` on the `<FragmentContainerView>` and `<LinearLayout>`, but that's incidental.

Comment: @MikeM. great it worked :) thank you. If you add this as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: No problem. I'm good. :-) Nothin' huge. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!